# FreeIPA Web UI extension - How far can I go?

Tags: ldap, freeipa

I noticed that when I add an attribute extension to the FreeIPA UI, I can add new "TEXT" fields only. can I change the field type? for example display a dropdown list instead of the text filed.

I know this question is not about programming. but it could be, depending on the answers I get.

Comment: I think you are better to ask these questions on freeipa-devel@ mailing list.

Comment: Check the link for the answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/692436/extending-ldap-and-freeipa/692685#692685